# linux kernel skb process function __netif_receive_skb_core() what is the use of pt_prev

Tags: networking, kernel

when reading linux kernel received packets process function  __netif_receive_skb_core().
I found the ptype logical is strange,

```
pt_prev = NULL;

    list_for_each_entry_rcu(ptype, &ptype_all, list) {
            if (pt_prev)
                    ret = deliver_skb(skb, pt_prev, orig_dev);
            pt_prev = ptype;
    }

    list_for_each_entry_rcu(ptype, &skb->dev->ptype_all, list) {
            if (pt_prev)
                    ret = deliver_skb(skb, pt_prev, orig_dev);
            pt_prev = ptype;
    }
```

why not just

```
list_for_each_entry_rcu(ptype, &ptype_all, list)
    ret = deliver_skb(skb, ptype, orig_dev);
```

what is the purpose that deliver previous ptype and save current ptype to pt_prev.